# How to set site files properly and avoid nginx 403?

Tags: nginx

I have a website with static and non-static content.

My project is hosted on github and to update it I simply push/pull.

My clone is under `/root` folder.

When I set up nginx to serve static files from `/root/my-site/static` I get `403`.

I tried linking `/var/www/my-site/static` to `/root/my-site/static` and tell nginx to serve from `/var/www/my-site/static` - but that showed `403` as well.

If I copy my files under `/var/www/` everything works well but then my pull process is cumbersome.

How can I make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The really short answer is to move your clone from `/root/` to `/var/www`.

A clone does not care where it lives, but access root's home directory is shielded for good reasons.